# How can I optimize SQLite ORDER BY rowid?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sorting

I want to query my sqlite db for all "level" values greater than 20, limit the result to 100 and order by rowid.

When ordering by rowid, the query is much slower. The database contains ~3 million records 
and the maximum value of level is 50. An index is created for level.

*This statement takes ~20ms:*

```
SELECT * FROM log WHERE level > 20 LIMIT 100
```

*This statement takes ~100ms:*

```
SELECT * FROM log WHERE level > 20 ORDER BY rowid LIMIT 100
```

*This statement takes ~1000ms (no rows with level value greater than 50 exists):*

```
SELECT * FROM log WHERE level > 50 ORDER BY rowid LIMIT 100
```

Is there a way to optimize this for faster ORDER BY query's?

This is the index used:

```
CREATE INDEX level_idx ON table (level)
```

Comment: Do you have any indexes?

Comment: I would check Index & its fragmentation, i would try read uncommitted, update statistics, and limit columns to only those that are required.

Comment: Hi CL, I updated the question. I'm using an index on level.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two possible methods to execute this query:

1. Search the first entry with `level>20` in the `level_idx` index, and then scan through all the following entries and fetch each corresponding row from the table.
   Because the index entries are not stored in `rowid` order, all the results must then be sorted.
   Then the first 100 of those can be returned.
2. Ignore the index.
   Scan through all rows of the table (which are already stored in `rowid` order), and return any where the `level` column matches.

The database estimates that the second method is faster.

If you estimate that the first method is faster, i.e., that so few rows match the `level` filter that fetching and sorting the remaining rows is faster than ignoring the non-matching rows while scanning through the table, then you can force the database to use the index with the INDEXED BY clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM log INDEXED BY level_idx
WHERE level > 20
ORDER BY rowid
LIMIT 100
```

However, forcing an index can lead to horrible slowdowns if your own estimate is wrong.

Comment: Thank you CL! New values are ~20ms for the second case and ~15ms for the third case. This really did the trick.

Comment: Check the worst case: what is the difference for `level > -1`?

Comment: You are right in what I assume is your guess that that check will be slow. For level > -1, the time is 8.5s... When I remove the explicit INDEXED BY from the query, time is back to ~25ms. Why is this?