# How to select row in the ordered table and retrieve a number of rows above and below it?

Tags: sqlite

So I have a large database and I want to order it by some value, like "earned_points", and with the userID find the user's earned points in the ordered table. After finding the user in the table I want to retrieve, for example, 5 users above him and 5 below him to create and show a ranking table in my code.

Now I tried doing that with creating a view table with rank (with window functions: OVER() and row_number()) and then selecting the rank from the temp table, something like:

```
CREATE VIEW temp_table AS
SELECT *, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY earned_points) FROM myTable;

SELECT id FROM temp_table WHERE rank > foundRank - 5 AND rank < foundRank + 5;
```

but the whole query along with creating the view table turns out to be very slow in my database. Is there any simple and fast way I could do this? I need the query to be under 10 ms long.

Comment: Do you have an index on the `earned_points` column? If not, create one and see if that improves times.

Comment: i did create an index and it made it around 4 times faster which brought me to around 20 ms for the query... and thats still too long for me. i also have a bunch of values i can sort the ranking list with, like number of kills etc. so im not sure if creating an index for all of those is the right way to go. i'd need to create around 30 index tables...

Answer (score 0):

Simple idea that may or may not work in your particular case: select based on a window around the current user's score:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
  WHERE earned_points > current_user_earned_points - X
        AND earned_points < current_user_earned_points + X
  ORDER BY earned_points
```

For some reasonable value of `X`. The idea would be that you usually select more people than you need, but you only show the ones near the player. This assumes the score distribution is fairly linear, otherwise you might select `X` as a function of `earned_points`.

Depending on the size of the table, this might be a lot faster even if you select dozens of unnecessary entries, since there is no need to do `row_number`.

The downside is that this method doesn't give an exact rank. Though if your table actually contains thousands of players, it might not really matter – you can just calculate an ok-ish estimate and display that to the user as their "rank", unless they are close to the top.

Also make sure to create an index over `earned_points`, if you haven't already. Perhaps you need to use `INDEXED BY`, as suggested e.g. in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24193973).

Comment: that would work but I receive a set number of users I need to show, so if I receive 10 as the number of users to be shown it has to be 10, and the scores are pretty random so it would be really hard to create a function of earned_points.

Comment: @BlackFlicka see edits; this might be faster even if you select 100 users instead of 10 (just to be on the safe side and never select fewer than 10).